# Is it safe to pull up copper pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, valve

We have a copper pipe coming up from the floor in our bathroom that likely needs to be cut due to some distortion where the compression valve used to be that is preventing a clean seal.

After cutting, the pipe will probably be too close to the floor to easily place a new valve on. There is some "play" the the pipe, meaning I can pull it up a bit to bring it higher. My question is: is this safe/okay to do? I'm not really sure why I am to move it up or down at all but I'm concerned that pulling it upwards could cause stress and/or damage

Comment: Hard to quantify, but does it feel 'easy' to pull it up? If yes, pull it up to attach a new compression shutoff. Ordinary copper has a fair amount of flex. That said, a poor solder joint can fail with movement, so if you can get underneath to verify that it isn't leaking, that's even better. If it was hard to move, or you were nervous, you could solder/sharkbite a stub on the existing to bring it higher.

Comment: Pulling up should be okay as long as no force is used.  Should try to check underneath and add supports(pipe clamps) for pipe.  Probably more stress is put on pipe by having it unsupported.

Comment: I would cut access in the wood floor rather than chance damaging a solder joint somewhere. My son has a similar situation right now except the copper pipe is in concrete - he is breaking concrete to get access.